# Cannot save map in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im not able to save a MAP in mongoose

This is my Schema

```
const tempSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      month: {
        type: Map,
        of: new mongoose.Schema({
          date: {
            type: Map,
            of: Number,
          },
          countries: {
            type: Map,
            of: Number,
          },
        }),
      },
    });

const yearsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    years : [ tempSchema ]
  })
```

and im inserting Data as follows

```
 const date = new Map();
        date.set("1", 90);
        date.set("2", 23);
        date.set("5", 28);
        date.set("19", 282);
        date.set("23", 18);
        const countries = new Map();
        countries.set("AFGHANISTAN", 90);
        countries.set("TIRANA", 23);
        countries.set("ALGIERS", 28);
        countries.set("LUANDA", 282);
        countries.set("YEREVAN", 18);
        const month = new Map();

        month.set("JANUARY", { date: date, countries: countries })
        const newYear = new Years()
        newYear.years.push(month)
        newYear.save()
```

It gets saved successfully when , i look at my mongoDB database, i just see a **_id** of document nothing else , First i taught it was because of nesting , i tried without nesting,
still same result , Just an **_id**

```
const tempSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  month: {
    type: Map,
    of: Number,
  },
});
```

Any help ?

Comment: I tried your example and it gets saved as expected, isn't it the problem of missing await in front of `newTemp.save()` ?

Comment: Can you try embedding it in an array like ,embedding it in another new schema like
 new Schema(
   { years: [ tempSchema ]
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're pushing to an array you need to pass an object representing `tempSchema` so your code should be like below:

```
const newYear = new Years()
newYear.years.push({month});

await newYear.save();
```

In your case you're pushing JavaScript `Map` directly which is different than `yearsSchema` expects.